# Не корректно работает выпадающие меню

Tags: javascript, html, css

Проблема заключается в том, что выпадающий блок (`.head__list-nav`) не скрывается и не корректно из-за этого появляется. Также псведоэлемент блока (`.head__item_open::after`) не поворачивается при нажатии на его родителя (`.head__item_open`).

```js
const menu = document.querySelectorAll(".head__item_open");

menu.forEach(menu => {
    menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
        menu.classList.toggle("active");
    })
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}
.head__list-nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 419px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.head__link {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 150%;
  color: #333333;
}

.head__item_open {
  position: relative;
}

.head__item_open.active .head__list-drop {
  max-height: 1000px;
  min-width: 205px;
  width: 100%;
}

.head__item_open.active ~ .head__item_open .head__item_open::after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

.head__item_open::after {
  content: "?";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: -14px;
}

.head__list-drop {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 27px 0 24px 23px;
  background-color: #da4523;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 48px rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.4);
          box-shadow: 0 20px 48px rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.4);
  border-radius: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: -25px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.4s ease;
  transition: all 1.4s ease;
  max-width: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.head__item-drop {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.head__link:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
  transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1749B3;
  color: #1749B3;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.head__link-drop:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
  transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
  color: #1749B3;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.head__link-drop {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 150%;
  color: #171717;
}
```

```html
<ul class="head__list-nav">
    <li class="head__item head__item_open"><a class="head__link" href="#">Subscriptions</a>
    <ul class="head__list-drop">
        <li class="head__item-drop"><a class="head__link-drop" href="#">Netflix</a>
        <li class="head__item-drop"><a class="head__link-drop" href="#">YouTube Premium</a>
        <li class="head__item-drop"><a class="head__link-drop" href="#">Spotify</a>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="head__item"><a class="head__link" href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li class="head__item"><a class="head__link" href="#">Support</a></li>
    <li class="head__item"><a class="head__link" href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Отсутствуют закрывающие теги для элементов списка в блоке `.head__list-drop`
- Для `.head__list-drop` установлен `padding: 27px 0 24px 23px;`, что
  уже задает его минимальную высоту и ширину, в этом случае
  `max-height`|`max-width` учитываться не будет. Паддинг необходимо перенести в `.head__item_open.active .head__list-drop`
- `.head__item_open.active~.head__item_open .head__item_open::after` неправильный селектор, нужен `.active.head__item_open::after`
- Везде установлен `transition: all`, указывайте конкретные анимации (высота, ширина и т.п.)

```js
const menu = document.querySelectorAll(".head__item_open");

menu.forEach(menu => {
  menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
    menu.classList.toggle("active");
  })
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.head__list-nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 419px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.head__link {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 150%;
  color: #333333;
}

.head__item_open {
  position: relative;
}

.head__item_open.active .head__list-drop {
  max-height: 1000px;
  min-width: 205px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 27px 0 24px 23px;
}

.active.head__item_open::after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

.head__item_open::after {
  content: "?";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: -14px;
}

.head__list-drop {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  background-color: #da4523;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 48px rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 48px rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.4);
  border-radius: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: -25px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.4s ease;
  transition: all 1.4s ease;
  max-width: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.head__item-drop {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.head__link:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
  transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1749B3;
  color: #1749B3;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.head__link-drop:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
  transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
  color: #1749B3;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.head__link-drop {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 150%;
  color: #171717;
}
```

```html
<ul class="head__list-nav">
  <li class="head__item head__item_open"><a class="head__link" href="#">Subscriptions</a>
    <ul class="head__list-drop">
      <li class="head__item-drop"><a class="head__link-drop" href="#">Netflix</a></li>
      <li class="head__item-drop"><a class="head__link-drop" href="#">YouTube Premium</a></li>
      <li class="head__item-drop"><a class="head__link-drop" href="#">Spotify</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="head__item"><a class="head__link" href="#">FAQ</a></li>
  <li class="head__item"><a class="head__link" href="#">Support</a></li>
  <li class="head__item"><a class="head__link" href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```